# Makefile rule that depends on all files under a directory (including within subdirectories)

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make, glob

One rule in my Makefile zips an entire directory (`res/`) into a ZIP file. Obviously, this rule needs to execute when *any* file under the `res/` directory changes. Thus, I want the rule to have as a prerequisite all files underneath that directory. How can I implement this rule?

In Bash [with the `globstar` option enabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob/49917#49917), you can obtain a list of all the files in that directory using the wildcard pattern `res/**/*`. However, it doesn't seem to work if you specify it as a prerequisite in the Makefile:

```
filename.jar: res/**/*
```

Even after `touch`ing a file in `res/`, Make still reports

```
make: `filename.jar' is up to date.
```

so clearly it is not recognizing the pattern.

If I declare the directory itself as a prerequisite:

```
filename.jar: res
```

then Make will not re-execute when a file is modified (I think `make` only looks at the modified date of the directory itself, which only changes when immediate children are added, removed, or renamed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Makefile: depend on every file of a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656913/makefile-depend-on-every-file-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This:

```
filename.jar: $(wildcard res/**/*)
```

seems to work, at least on some platforms.

**EDIT:**

Or better, just cut the knot:

```
filename.jar: $(shell find res -type f)
```

Comment: The `wildcard` suggestion doesn't work for me, but `find` does work. (I used just `$(shell find res)` in order to trigger it when files are deleted as well.)

Comment: Caveat: If you *remove* one of the input files after making the jar, make will not notice. To be able to detect file removals, you could store the list in a file, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236145/force-gnu-make-to-rebuild-objects-affected-by-compiler-definition/3237349#3237349

Comment: @slowdog: True, but for this purpose (ZIP archive) I don't think it matters.

Comment: @Beta: How about this: Developer A deletes a file from the `res` directory which they think is unused, runs `make`, tests the jar file, commits. Developer B makes a clean checkout of the code, runs `make`, gets a broken build.

Comment: @slowdog: Then A broke the build (and failed to test it). The makefile can't determine whether the file is needed-- oh, wait... maybe it can... Well, anyway, a developer who has the power to remove a file (and there must be such a person) should know better than to test one set of files and then check another in; having Make detect a removal won't protect against that level of bad judgement.

Comment: @slowdog: When a file is deleted, the modified date of `res` directory will also be changed. Adding depency of `res` directory itself may solve the problem. Simply remove `-type f` from `find` command.

Comment: To allow spaces `filename.jar: $(shell find res -type f | sed 's/ /\\ /g')` seems to work for me

Comment: The `**` syntax does not exist in any version of Make that I know of. See e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards

Comment: By the way, if you want to do this in a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html), you can use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html). For instance, `bin/%.jar: $$(shell find res/%)` would create a pattern rule for any `bin/<module>.jar`, which depends on all of the files and folders (recursively) in `res/<module>`.