# How to tar a directory with using makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have few files in sub directories, all the files are just text files like faq, user guides.There are no c/cpp src code
in it. Following is the file and directory structure.

```
scr
|_Makefile                     #Top level Makefile
|_other_dirs
|_some_other_dirs
|_mydir
   |_Makefile                  #Makefile of mydir, need to put some code here
   |_dir1
   |  |_textfile0
   |  |_textfile1 
   |_dir2
      |_textfile2
      |_textfile3
```

Question, How can I tar the contents of dir1 and dir2 into one tar ball? I tried searching over internet about the Makefile and how to use it to create the take ball from top Makefile but no success yet. I am not  very familiar with Makefiles, any starting point will be appreciated. Thanks.

Following is my novice attempt to have a very basic Makefile:

```
 -->cat Makefile
mydir.tgz : *
    tar -zcvf mydir.tgz mydir/

 -->make
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Idea is to run top Makefile and have tar file generated for mydir.

Comment: Your question has a lot in common with [Makefile rule that depends on all files under a directory (including within subdirectories)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14289513/1380680).

Comment: Missing separator means you didn't use TAB to indent the action line. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop

Comment: thanks, `tab` was the problem.

Comment: @monk Your current approach will not properly detect when the tar-file has to be remade or not. If you add a file in one of the subdirectories, then `make` will not re-create the tar file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add all files and directories in `mydir` recursively as a prerequisite of `mydir.tgz`. That way, your tar file will be executed if, and only if, a change occurs somewhere under `mydir`. For example like this:

```
mydir.tgz: $(shell find mydir)
    tar -zcvf mydir.tgz mydir
```

The line with the `tar` command should start with at `TAB`.

Most of the mechanisms of this answer are also described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14289513/13806800), but it seemed to make sense to me to add it here to concisely answer your specific question.

Comment: To handle deleted files, you need to include the timestamp of directories.

Comment: @o11c I have changed my answer. I think it is better and simpler now, thanks to you :-)

Comment: Is it possible to use the `ar` syntax of make to do the same, you know syntax is `archive(member)` compatible with ar, but is it so with tar?

Comment: @Sandburg Out of the box that does not seem to be the case. However, the `gmake` manual section [11.4 Suffix Rules for Archive Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Archive-Suffix-Rules) looks like a promising mechanism to support using `tar` in stead of `ar` to with the archive syntax.