# Why does make copy a file onto another file? (Target depends on an entire folder.)

Tags: makefile

I have a directory with test inputs and outputs. I wanted `make` to automatically test my program against this directory after build, for convenience. Thus I needed to somehow force the `test` target of `Makefile` to depend on the entire testing directory (it's called `good`, because it contains valid inputs and outputs for the program)

I read this question and the accepted answer and the comments about deleted files under this answer: [Makefile rule that depends on all files under a directory (including within subdirectories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289513/makefile-rule-that-depends-on-all-files-under-a-directory-including-within-subd) And, incorporating advice from this answer & comments, I came out with this:

```
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ cat Makefile
test : test.sh $(shell find good)
    ./test.sh
my@comp:~/wtfdir$
```

For the sake of MCVE, `test.sh` is very rudimentary:

```
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ cat test.sh
echo "blah"
my@comp:~/wtfdir$
```

However, I noticed, this behaves in a rather unexpected way:

```
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ ls good
test1  test1.out
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ make
./test.sh
blah
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ touch good/test1
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ make
cp good/test1 good/test1.out
./test.sh
blah
my@comp:~/wtfdir$
```

Why (expletive redacted) does modifying `test1` cause `make` to overwrite `test1.out` with `test1`??? I'm not a big fan of data losses, you know.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Make appears to be GNU Make. Here's why this happens. Your recipe:

```
test : test.sh $(shell find good)
    ./test.sh
```

adds to the prerequisites of `test` every file and directory that is listed
by `find good` in the current directory, which happen to be:

```
good
good/test1
good/test1.out
```

So to make target `test`, Make begins by determining if any of the specified
or built-in recipes require it to rebuild any of the prerequsities:

```
test.sh good good/test1 good/test1.out
```

Among its built-in recipes it finds:

```
%.out: %
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    @rm -f $@
     cp $< $@
```

as you can verify by running:

```
$ make --print-data-base | grep -A4 '%.out'
```

The rule for this recipe is matched by:

```
good/test1.out: good/test1
```

and by doing:

```
$ touch good/test1
```

you have made `good/test1.out` out of date with respect to `good/test1`.

So make executes the recipe:

```
    @rm -f good/test1.out
     cp good/test1 good/test1.out
```

the visible output of which is what you observed:

```
cp good/test1 good/test1.out
```

Then it proceeds with the recipe for `test`:

```
./test.sh
blah
```

There is always a risk of such booby-traps if you write a makefile that blindly
generates at runtime some set of preqrequisites or targets you don't know beforehand.

You could avoid this one in particular by explicitly deleting the offending
implicit pattern rule in your makefile by writing:

```
%.out: %
```

with no recipe. And you can avoid all possible booby-traps of this sort by disabling *all*
built-in recipes, with:

```
$ make --no-builtin-rules ...
```

but that will require you to write for yourself any builtin-recipes that your
makefile relies on.

The best solution for you is probably to amend your makefile as follows:

```
PREREQS := $(shell find good)

test : test.sh $(PREREQS)
    ./test.sh

$(PREREQS): ;
```

Then the last line explicitly specifies an [empty recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Empty-Recipes.html)
for each of the `$(PREREQS)`, and Make will not consult any pattern rules for targets
that have explicit recipes.

You should additionally make `test` a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

```
.PHONY: test
```

for the avoidance of the booby-trap where something creates a file called `test` in the build directory.